# Hosting multiple MVC app versions on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, entity-framework-migrations

I've got a multi tenant asp.net mvc app hosted on iis 8. Each tenant has it's own database, an there is one database with tenants metadata like name, database-name...

As ORM i use Entity Framework with Code-First Migrations.

Now I've got a problem when update the application. because when i start the migration, the App is offline for all tenant because, entity framework can't connect to database with different migration version.

When all Databases are migrated i can start the IIS-Website and all Tenants come online again!

Is there a way to achieve such database migration? **OR** Am I able to host multiple versions of an MVC App on same Domain (perhaps routing per e.g. http-Header or meta Database)?